# can't display API in a UITableViewController. "[DriverStanding] has no member Driver"

Tags: swift, uitableview, codable, json-api

I trying to display a list of drivers from a formula API.  This will displayed on a UITableViewController. I have programmatically displayed the UITableView but unfortunately, there is no data.  The error I am getting is that I am not able to get the givenName and family name to display in the UITableViewCell.  I am using the Codable protocol to get which is in Swift 4.  Below is the code that I have so far.

```
struct F1Data: Codable {
    let mrData: MRData

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mrData = "MRData"
    }
}

struct MRData: Codable {
    let xmlns: String
    let series: String
    let url: String
    let limit, offset, total: String
    let standingsTable: StandingsTable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case xmlns, series, url, limit, offset, total
        case standingsTable = "StandingsTable"
    }
}

struct StandingsTable: Codable {
    let season: String
    let standingsLists: [StandingsList]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case season
        case standingsLists = "StandingsLists"
    }
}

struct StandingsList: Codable {
    let season, round: String
    let driverStandings: [DriverStanding]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case season, round
        case driverStandings = "DriverStandings"
    }
}

struct DriverStanding: Codable {
    let position, positionText, points, wins: String
    let driver: Driver
    let constructors: [Constructor]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case position, positionText, points, wins
        case driver = "Driver"
        case constructors = "Constructors"
    }
}

struct Constructor: Codable {
    let constructorId: String
    let url: String
    let name: String
    let nationality: String
}

struct Driver: Codable {
    let driverId: String
    let url: String
    let givenName, familyName, dateOfBirth, nationality: String
}

class f1TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var champions = [F1Data]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/website_description"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.title = "Champion Drivers"
        fetchJSON()
    }

    private func fetchJSON(){
        let jsonUrlString = "https://ergast.com/api/f1/1999/driverstandings.json"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    // Swift 4.1
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    self.champions = try decoder.decode([F1Data].self, from: data)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return champions.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")

        let champion = champions[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = champion.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].driverStandings.Driver
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(course.numberOfLessons)
        return cell
    }
}
```

I know how to iterate through the array and show the data in the console.  It is just trying to show this in the tableviewcell.

```
let season = f1Data.mrData.standingsTable.season
let firstDriver =  f1Data.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].driverStandings
for driver in firstDriver {
    print("\(driver.driver.givenName) \(driver.driver.familyName)")
}

print(season)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `driver` instead of `Driver`?

Comment: If I do ```driver``` I get the error ```Value of type '[DriverStanding]' has no member 'driver'``` .  Basically how do iterate through ``[DriverStanding]``` ?

Comment: That's because `driverStandings` is an array.  You need to pick one of them before referencing the `driver` member.

Comment: thanks for the reply Philip but how do I do that?

Comment: The obvious answer is "use a subscript like you do with `standingsLists`" but is that what you're really asking?

Comment: What I want to display is the givenName and familyName in a tableviewcell

Comment: I understand but `champion.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].driverStandings` is an array of `DriverStanding`.  Which element in the array contains the `driver` that you want to use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190206/discussion-between-altbrian-and-phillip-mills).

Comment: Is this related to [JSON API specification](https://jsonapi.org/) at all?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?